# JS compression ratio in Advagg module

Tags: 7, css-js-aggregation

I am trying to use AdvAgg in my Drupal 7 site. I am using a local server for running tests.

The issue is that the module doesn't compress (php-jsmin) all the JavaScript files, which is causing a bad score in page speed insights.

After some debugging, I found out the problem: The uncompressed file didn't have a compress ratio between 0.1 and 0.9 so it was being aggregated as it was.

I'm talking exactly about advagg_js_compress.module file, lines below 143:

```
// Set to "-2" if compression ratio sucks (it's already compressed)
```

Why is necessary a min ratio? Could set min ratio to 0 so that all JavaScript files are processed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes things compress too well; ie empty string. Sometimes things don't compress at all; ie already compressed. In both cases I opt to use the original file since minification of already minified js can sometimes cause js errors. You can variable set it if you want to adjust the min/max cutoff.

Comment: Ok Mikeytown2, thanks. As far as I can see jsmin should't leave the string empty in any case... Anyway, I will adjust min ratio to 0. I think I contacted you on G+. Better this way, I guess… I'm "playing" with the module and I found some issues I want to correct. I will write here in case I find it necessary.

Thanks again!

Comment: The module issue queue is the best place to contact me in regards to a specific module.